# How to map database enum to xml enum

Tags: java, xml, enums

I've got an existing database that implements an (encoded) enum:
A
B
C

And I need to transform to a (self describing) XML enum:
Apple
Banana
Carrot

Is there an established pattern in Java for doing this? My current approach feels clunky (and can't be re-used for other enums since you cant inherit/extend java enums)

```
public enum Food {  
    Apple("A", "Apple"),
    Banana("B", "Banana"),
    Carrot("C", "Carrot");

    private final String databaseCode;
    private final String xmlCode;

    private static final Map<String, Food> databaseCodeToFood = 
        new HashMap<String, Food>();
    static {
        for(Food f: values()) {
            databaseCodeToFood.put(f,getDatabaseCode(), f);
        }
    }

    private Food(String databaseCode, String xmlCode) {
        this.databaseCode = databaseCode;
        this.xmlCode = xmlCode;
    }

    public String getDatabaseCode() {
        return databaseCode;
    }

    public String getXmlCode() {
        return xmlCode;
    }

    public static Food fromDatabaseCode(String databaseCode) {
        return databaseCodeToFood.get(databaseCode);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please explain in details *can't be re-used for other enums*.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty standard way of mapping between enum values in Java. Why is it clunky? You have a quick hashed lookup.

Comment: @Braj Java enums can't extend anything since they allready implicitly extend java.lang.Enum. So I can't place the mapping logic in AbstractXmlCodeDatabaseCodeEnum and have each enum inherit from it. Does that leave me with cutting and pasting the mapping logic for each new enum?

Answer (score 0):

Implement [`Converter<S,T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html)

The specific implementation is not important.